# how to show billing address form with shipping address form at palce of Order Summary in magento 2 on checkout page

Tags: php, node.js, magento2, checkout

I have no idea how it is possible 
my code is:

```
class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{

   /**
    * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
    * @param array $jsLayout
    * @return array
    */

   public function afterProcess(
       \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
       array $jsLayout
   )
   {
       // get billing address form at billing step
       $billingAddressForm = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'];

       // move address form to shipping step
       $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billing-address-form'] = $billingAddressForm; 

       // remove form from billing step
       unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']);

       return $jsLayout;
   }
}
```